# How kernel prints partitions of block devices in dmesg?

Tags: linux-kernel

On kernel boot or block device added, it prints the partitions of block devices like:

```
[    4.168995]  nvme0n1: p1 p2
[    4.202666]  nvme2n1: p1
[    4.228494]  nvme1n1: p1
[    5.104852]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    5.681698]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[    5.717981]  sde: sde1 sde2
[    5.718320]  sdb: sdb1
[    5.727097]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
```

I'd like to know in which piece of kernel code these messages are printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer (for kernel 5.17).

This message is printed in `block/partitions/core.c:check_partition()`, but it is generated by multiple functions. First it allocates a page for `pp_buf` to hold the message, and puts the block name to it. Taking `nvme0` as an example.

For block devices ending with digits like `nvme0` or `nbd0`, it replaces the name to `p` after printing the device to buffer.

```c
snprintf(state->name, BDEVNAME_SIZE, "%s", hd->disk_name);
snprintf(state->pp_buf, PAGE_SIZE, " %s:", state->name);
// " nvme0:"
if (isdigit(state->name[strlen(state->name)-1]))
        sprintf(state->name, "p");
```

Then it calls the funtions in `check_part[]` to check if the block device has a supported partition table. Here I use efi (GPT) as the example. The function loops the partition table entries and calls `put_partition()` to append partitions to `pp_buf`. `put_partition()` (in `block/partitions/check.h`) uses the device name and partition index to form the partition name.

```c
snprintf(tmp, sizeof(tmp), " %s%d", p->name, n);
// n == 1, formatted string: " p1", pp_buf: " nvme0: p1"
```

After the loop, it appends `\n` to the `pp_buf` and returns to `check_partition()`, then prints `pp_buf`, giving the message we saw in dmesg.

```
 nvme0: p1 p2
```